# Clock inoperative, 2006 Toyota Yaris

Tags: toyota, yaris, instrument-cluster

Pictured below is the circuit board of the instrument cluster on my 2006 Toyota Yaris. The clock does not work and an electrician told me that the 4 transistors below were burnt and needed to be replaced. How can I find out what kind of transistors they are? I can't find any information how to identify them.

Electrician told that 4 of them were burned - MK 5X. He says it's easy to replace them, but you have to know what they are. I called Toyota and they did't know. They just offered new instrument panel for 300+ Eur, but these transistors cost around 1 Euro. :D 4 of them are bad, red square was drawn before they were tested.

[image]

Comment: It's not normal for 4 transistors to release their magic smoke. You probably have bigger problems.

Comment: Looks like ordinary BJTs, possibly SC-73 package, based on the 'E' marking. That heat discoloration is not necessarily an indication that something is wrong with them, nor is replacing them likely to end happily, I'm afraid.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it's about electronics components. It should _not_ have been migrated.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I disagree, [see this meta post](http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/1346/85) and [this chat discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21076617#21076617)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone for reply!

I gave this to one electrician and he told but that 4 of them are burned. And he wanted quite a lot for replacement only because he knows what kind there are. Also I found topic with the same problem and the guy replaced them and clock was working, only he got these transistors from same circuit board.

This is the topic.

[Dashboard clock goes off](http://www.yarisworld.com/forums/showthread.php?t=44172)

Comment: If you accociate your accounts you will be able to take ownership of the question

Comment: Which ones are you refering too? The ones with 022 on them or the ones with MK 5X?

Comment: I am talking about MK 5x

Comment: Register your account, then associate it with your electronics account and it will give you ownership of the question.

Answer (score 1):

They are 22 ohm chip (or surface mount) resistors not transistors.

They may not be bad, Toyota Corollas had issues with the solder joint and you may only need to reheat the joint, or possibly need to add solder to them. [See this YouTube video on repairing the Corolla.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lFwKA2dDb94)

Comment: I think he was talking about the ones one the right, not the left. T529 would have been one of them.

Comment: @Paulster2 But there are only three of those inside the red box in the picture. There are 4 resistors, and the solder joints are brown, which the OP might consider burnt. And Toyota has a known problem with the resistors. But I could be wrong and the OP hasn't replied back to me :(

Comment: You are probably right. I bow to your wisdom (as always).

Comment: @Paulster2 Nope, I'm wrong again, lol OP is talking about the transistors.

Comment: It's all good ... you are *still* the man and have maintained your standing in my book :D